# Price Format in Backend and Emails

Tags: magento2, price, currency

I managed to format the price **without** decimals modifyng the following files:

- LINE 38 vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-utils.js
- LINE 19 vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/PriceCurrencyInterface.php

Does somebody knows where are those files?
Example of a thousand 1.000

Comment: Those files are in the path you provided :)

Comment: Yes..but i was talking about removing decimals globally, modifyng those files only change the front end, not emails and backend. In some countries like mine Chile, we do not use decimals

Comment: Disculpa, no había entendido tu pregunta. Yo había preguntado como quitar los decimales y no he recibido respuesta clara. Tú lo lograste sólo modificando esos 2 archivos?

Comment: Con esos archivos debes hacer un "override" para no tener problemas al actualizar el magento, pero me falta encontrar los que controlan los templates del email y backend........

Comment: Me podrías indicar la ruta en la que creaste tus archivos para hacer el override? No consigo todavía eliminar los decimales en el front end